# Is there any way to search for instagram stories?

Tags: instagram, facebook-business-manager

Previously, I was able to search for my Instagram stories by their captions using `business.facebook.com`. However, I've noticed that the search option no longer includes the 'story' option, and I can only search for photos, videos, and reels as post types. Is there any alternative method or workaround to search for stories?

[image: facebook business manager]